# AFRAME: Event on completion of dynamic adding of component

Tags: aframe

My use-case is as follows:

In a loop, entities are being created and components are being set up. This is via a json-object that is being passed to the function. The question I have is how best to get an event that the whole set of entities and their components are being initialised. The code is something like this

```
var parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
var ent = document.createElement('a-entity');
parent.appendChild(ent);
for(var i =0; i = components.length; i++) {
   var arr = components[i];
   var cl = arr[0]; // class name
   var attr = arr[2]; // component name
   var attrV = arr[3]; // component data
   ent.setAttribute('class', cl);
   AFRAME.utils.entity.setComponentProperty(ent, attr, attrV);
   //ent.setAttribute(attr, attrV); tried with this too
}
console.log('loop completed')
```

The loop completed gets logged before the completion of the loading of some of the components. I would like to have some sort of a call back to know that all the components have been completed loaded.

There seems to be an event `componentinitialized` but it sends a return for only 1 component. My real requirement (not reflected in above code) is that an entity can have multiple components added.

To use the above, I may have to set this event for every component and keep track of whether it has been completed or not. Just wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Just to add, using `componentinitialized` seems more complicated because aframe auto adds entities like position and rotation too. The current solution is to give a timeout before callback. Obviously, not happy about it.

Answer (score 1):

Entities emit the "loaded" event. It should be easier than listening for each component initialization within the entity.

Try out:

```
entity.addEventListener("loaded", (e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hvb410ng/3/).

Comment: You can also create the parent dynamically append the children and then the parent to the scene. When the parent emits ‘loaded` all the children will have loaded as well